# No module named 'rocksdb' on Mac OSX Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, rocksdb

I have installed rocksdb on my mac using the [official documentation](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and then ran a command `pip3 install python-rocksdb`. However, when I try to import rocksdb, I face a `ModuleNotFoundError` on my Mac OSX. The `pip3 freeze` command displays the following:

```
astroid==2.1.0
autopep8==1.4.3
futures==2.2.0
isort==4.3.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
lz4==2.1.6
mccabe==0.6.1
plyvel==1.0.5
pycodestyle==2.4.0
pylint==2.2.2
python-rocksdb==0.6.9
six==1.12.0
virtualenv==16.3.0
wrapt==1.10.11
```

And some other useful commands are:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.2

➜  ~ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

I am running the command wihch has following contents(a clone of the rocksdb official repo):

```
total 13008
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   322B Jan 26 06:42 AUTHORS
   72 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff    36K Jan 26 06:42 CMakeLists.txt
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   249B Jan 26 06:42 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   706B Jan 26 06:42 CONTRIBUTING.md
   40 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff    18K Jan 26 06:42 COPYING
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.5K Jan 26 06:42 DEFAULT_OPTIONS_HISTORY.md
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   763B Jan 26 06:42 DUMP_FORMAT.md
  152 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff    72K Jan 26 06:42 HISTORY.md
   16 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   7.5K Jan 26 06:42 INSTALL.md
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.1K Jan 26 06:42 LANGUAGE-BINDINGS.md
   24 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff    11K Jan 26 06:42 LICENSE.Apache
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.5K Jan 26 06:42 LICENSE.leveldb
  136 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff    66K Jan 26 06:42 Makefile
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.8K Jan 26 06:42 README.md
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.0K Jan 26 06:42 ROCKSDB_LITE.md
   56 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff    27K Jan 26 06:42 TARGETS
   16 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   5.6K Jan 26 06:42 USERS.md
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.0K Jan 26 06:42 Vagrantfile
   32 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff    13K Jan 26 06:42 WINDOWS_PORT.md
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   436B Jan 26 06:42 appveyor.yml
    0 drwxr-xr-x    7 aviralsrivastava  staff   224B Jan 26 06:42 buckifier
    0 drwxr-xr-x   23 aviralsrivastava  staff   736B Jan 26 06:42 build_tools
    0 drwxr-xr-x    4 aviralsrivastava  staff   128B Jan 26 06:42 cmake
    0 drwxr-xr-x    4 aviralsrivastava  staff   128B Jan 26 06:42 coverage
    0 drwxr-xr-x   25 aviralsrivastava  staff   800B Jan 26 06:42 docs
    0 drwxr-xr-x   14 aviralsrivastava  staff   448B Jan 26 06:42 examples
    0 drwxr-xr-x    5 aviralsrivastava  staff   160B Jan 26 06:42 hdfs
    0 drwxr-xr-x    3 aviralsrivastava  staff    96B Jan 26 06:42 include
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   243B Jan 26 06:42 issue_template.md
    0 drwxr-xr-x   13 aviralsrivastava  staff   416B Jan 26 06:42 java
   64 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff    29K Jan 26 06:42 src.mk
    0 drwxr-xr-x    4 aviralsrivastava  staff   128B Jan 26 06:42 third-party
   16 -rw-r--r--    1 aviralsrivastava  staff   7.7K Jan 26 06:42 thirdparty.inc
    0 drwxr-xr-x   60 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.9K Jan 26 06:44 tools
    0 drwxr-xr-x   36 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.1K Jan 26 06:44 utilities
    0 drwxr-xr-x  136 aviralsrivastava  staff   4.3K Jan 26 06:45 table
    0 drwxr-xr-x   18 aviralsrivastava  staff   576B Jan 26 06:45 port
    0 drwxr-xr-x   22 aviralsrivastava  staff   704B Jan 26 06:45 options
    0 drwxr-xr-x   43 aviralsrivastava  staff   1.3K Jan 26 06:45 monitoring
    0 drwxr-xr-x   30 aviralsrivastava  staff   960B Jan 26 06:45 memtable
    0 drwxr-xr-x   26 aviralsrivastava  staff   832B Jan 26 06:45 env
    0 drwxr-xr-x  308 aviralsrivastava  staff   9.6K Jan 26 06:45 db
    0 drwxr-xr-x   16 aviralsrivastava  staff   512B Jan 26 06:45 cache
    0 drwxr-xr-x   13 root              staff   416B Jan 26 06:51 shared-objects
12280 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root              staff   6.0M Jan 26 06:54 librocksdb.5.18.0.dylib
    0 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root              staff    23B Jan 26 06:54 librocksdb.dylib -> librocksdb.5.18.0.dylib
    0 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root              staff    23B Jan 26 06:54 librocksdb.5.dylib -> librocksdb.5.18.0.dylib
    0 lrwxr-xr-x    1 root              staff    23B Jan 26 06:54 librocksdb.5.18.dylib -> librocksdb.5.18.0.dylib
    8 -rw-r--r--    1 root              staff   1.0K Jan 26 06:57 make_config.mk
    0 drwxr-xr-x  177 aviralsrivastava  staff   5.5K Jan 26 06:57 util
```

And this is from the directory `/Users/aviralsrivastava/dev/rocksdb`.

Comment: would you be able to provide a bit more details on where you are calling the `import rocksdb` from?

Comment: Updated the question. Also, why did you ask?

Comment: i am just wondering if you also have a different `python` version installed in your system and you accidentally were running that other `python` instead of `python3` from which you installed the `rocksdb` package

Comment: How can I check that if my `pip3 freeze` is returning the package installed?

Comment: are you using Anaconda?

Comment: No. I used pip. Also, with python I can import but not with python3 hence, I started using virtualenv.